# Implementing is_convertible trait for function and array types

Tags: c++, types, c++11, type-conversion, type-traits

I have (thanks to @Xeo) a relatively simple `is_convertible` implementation:

```
template<typename From, typename To>
struct is_convertible
{
private:
  static void foo(To);
  template<typename F>
  static auto test(int) -> decltype(foo(declval<F>()), void(), true_type{});
  template<typename>
  static auto test(...) -> false_type;
public:
  static constexpr bool value = decltype(test<From>(0))::value;
  constexpr operator bool() { return value; }
};
```

which works for "normal" stuff, and augmented with all cv-qualified `void` versions (which I believe should be compactable from my current 20 specializations for `void`), is pretty useful.

The problem is when I try array and function types:

```
typedef void Function();
typedef char Array[1];
```

Then these tests fail:

```
static_assert(!is_convertible<Function, Function>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Function&, Function>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Function*, Function>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Function*const, Function>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Array, const Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Array&, Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<Array&, const Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<const Array&, const Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<char*, Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<char*, const Array>(), "");
static_assert(!is_convertible<const char*, const Array>(), "");
```

Can the above trait be augmented to work for these types as well, or do I need specializations, and how would these look?

Comment: Why the `void()` in `static auto test(int) -> decltype(foo(declval<F>()), void(), true_type{});`?

Comment: @AndyProwl That was @Xeo's trick to prevent a user-defined `operator,` from messing things up. He said you cannot overload `operator,` on `void`.

Comment: Oh, I see. I would have never gotten that, thank you

Comment: Isn't it an option to partially specialize `is_convertible` for function and array types?

Comment: In which sense do they fail? On g++4.8 and clang++3.2 all of the form `static_assert(::is_convertible<A, B>(), "")` (note no `!`) with A, B from the examples you've given pass == are not triggered. E.g. shouldn't an `Array` be convertible to an `Array&`?

Comment: Why are you going through all the old-fashioned SFINAE rigmarole with `...` etc if this is C++11? Just derive the primary template from `std::false_type` and use `std::enable_if` on a partial specialization derived from `true_type`.

Comment: You seem to be testing the wrong behaviour.

Comment: @Dyp you must have something weird going on. The tests are fine on [GCC 4.7.2](http://ideone.com/Qpefdk) and the [libc++ tests](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/test/utilities/meta/meta.rel/is_convertible.pass.cpp) (where I got these test cases) contain these exact `static_assert`s.

Comment: @rubenvb 1) I confused `From` and `To`. Of course, `Array&` shouldn't be implicitly convertible to `Array`. 2) Your implementation differs from the Standard requirements: it gives non-compliant results for (some of) those tests. E.g. for `Array&`->`Array`, where `static void foo(char[1])` is decayed to `static void foo(char*)` which then can accept `Array&`. Guessing from the [libc++ implementation](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/include/type_traits) this could get complicated.